# ddclient not working without sudo

Tags: networking, sudo, chmod, dyndns, ddclient

When I run ddclient (DynamicDns Updator) without sudo, I get

```
WARNING:  file /etc/ddclient.conf: Cannot open file '/etc/ddclient.conf'. (Permission denied)
stat() on closed filehandle FD at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 934.
Use of uninitialized value $mode in bitwise and (&) at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 935.
readline() on closed filehandle FD at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 947.
WARNING:  file /etc/ddclient.conf: Cannot open file '/etc/ddclient.conf'. (Permission denied)
stat() on closed filehandle FD at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 934.
Use of uninitialized value $mode in bitwise and (&) at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 935.
readline() on closed filehandle FD at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 947.
WARNING:  file /var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache: Cannot open file '/var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache'. (Permission denied)
stat() on closed filehandle FD at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 934.
Use of uninitialized value $mode in bitwise and (&) at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 935.
readline() on closed filehandle FD at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 947.
```

However it works fine with sudo.

Do I need to `chmod` some files? If yes, please explain how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a default setup root runs [**ddclient**](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ddclient/wiki) as a daemon using setting from `/etc/ddclient.conf`. Runtime options are defined in `/etc/default/ddclient`.

We are able to start ddclient with another configuration file by using the option:

```
ddclient -file <path>
```

For further options see also the [ddclient wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ddclient/wiki/Usage).

It is not recommended to change permissions for the default files as this may lead to security issues.